# How do I turn off safebrowsing.io that comes with the Cox Panoramic Wifi?

Tags: wifi, panoramas, cox

I recently upgraded my wifi with Cox Cable and after installing their Panoramic Wifi device (that is both a modem and a router), I kept getting an Unsafe destination message with a button to click that said "Proceed Anyway".

I would get this message when I went to pages on the website space I lease from Hostgator that does not have an SSL installed, so http://somepage.html

I was unable to find the way to turn off this feature in the Panoramic Wifi device.

Any ideas?

Thanks, 
Steve

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer.

Enter URL in Chrome
   http://192.168.0.1/

which brings you to the Cox Wifi setup window

userid: admin

password: (you need to know your password for this)

Once  logged in:

1. Click the "Parental Control"  menu on the left
2. Click on the "Managed Services" submenu
3. You will see a list of all your connected devices
   Turn the button to YES, in the TRUSTED column, for all devices you trust
4. Logoff

Now go to non-SSL (http://example.html) site

You may still get the error page initially, but click on more non-SSL sites
and even the first one you used again and the "Proceed AnyWay" page will go away.